# I want to make a view

Tags: sql-server

This my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StandardRoom](
[StandardRoomId] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[RoomType] [varchar](15) NULL,
[Rate] [smallmoney] NULL,
[RoomDeparment] [varchar](15) NULL,
[PlaceNb] [char](1) NULL,
[PatientId1] [char](12) NULL,
[PatientId2] [char](12) NULL,
[PatientId3] [char](12) NULL,
[PatientId4] [char](12) NULL,
[BedId1] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[BedId2] [char](4) NULL,
[BedId3] [char](4) NULL,
[BedId4] [char](4) NULL,
[Full] [char](1) NOT NULL,
```

So I want to create a view  to see (BedId1 if PatientId1=null), (BedId2 if PatientId2=null)
(BedId3 if PatientId3 = null), (BedId4 if PatientId4 =null)

Thank's for helping me!

For guys voting down because They think this table is not normalize, Yes Its true , but I Have my reason to do this in the context of my DATABASE...

Comment: Start by putting your table into at least First Normal Form. I wouldn't want to stay in the hospital that has a database with these kinds of tables - what else is poorly maintained?

Comment: Read up on Database Normalization!!!

Comment: I konw but I have table StandardRoom whit 4 bed and 4 Patient, table Semi-private Room whit 2 bed and 2 Patient And table private Room whit 1 bed and 1 Patient And finnaly a table for the bed whit id etc but I dont konw when  i can normalize thoses...

Comment: For guys voting down because They think this table is not normalize, Yes Its true , but I Have my reason to do this in the context of my DATABASE... Thank's for your vote down!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I didn't downvote because of your terrible structure, it's because of your terrible question which is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_StandardRoom]
AS
select [StandardRoomId] ,
[RoomType] ,
[Rate] ,
[RoomDeparment] ,
[PlaceNb] ,
[PatientId1] ,
[PatientId2] ,
[PatientId3] ,
[PatientId4] ,
case when PatientId1 IS NULL then [BedId1] 
when PatientId2 IS NULL then [BedId2] 
when PatientId3 IS NULL then [BedId3] 
when PatientId4 IS NULL then [BedId4] 
end as BedId,
[Full] 
from [dbo].[v_StandardRoom]
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question - as opposed to just commenting about the poor table structure =)

Comment: @jadarnel27: There are plenty of valid reasons to have a structure like that.

Comment: Oh, I agree.  I was referring to all of the not-so-helpful question comments.